# how to put users prompted response into clipboard (formatted differently)

Tags: format, clipboard, paste, prompt

I'm working on tampermonkey script that prompts somebody to type in a number, then again for some different text, and so on. Once all the prompts are fulfilled, I would like them to be copied to the clipbaord in a certain format. for example,

```
    var 1 = prompt("what is the players name")
    var 2 = prompt("what is the players id")
    var 3 = prompt("what is the players favorite food")
```

then i would like it to format as such in plain text, and copy it to the persons clipboard

(favorite food =var 3 id  =var2 name=var1)
(copy)

I'm a complete js noobie and have minimal experience, your help is much appreciated.
thank you in advance.

Comment: Please search stackoverflow for pasting data into the clipboard in the particular programming language and O/S you're using.

Comment: i did, nothing.

Comment: Which language and O/S are you using?

Comment: javascript, windows 10

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript